# Using Categories in Swift and Using them in different class

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to swift. I am working on creating the categories in swift. I have created one category for `UIColor`. I need to call this in some other class. Currently I am calling this by

```
messageview.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexaString: "31D433")
```

but it gives an error.

```
class Colorextension: UIColor {
    convenience init(hexaString:String) {
        self.init(
            red:   CGFloat( strtoul( String(Array(hexaString.characters)[1...2]), nil, 16) ) / 255.0,
            green: CGFloat( strtoul( String(Array(hexaString.characters)[3...4]), nil, 16) ) / 255.0,
            blue:  CGFloat( strtoul( String(Array(hexaString.characters)[5...6]), nil, 16) ) / 255.0, alpha: 1 )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In swift you use extensions, placed in global scope:

```
extension UIColor {
    convenience init?(hexaString:String) {
        if hexaString.characters.count < 6 {return nil}
        self.init(
            red:   CGFloat( strtoul( String(Array(hexaString.characters)[0...1]), nil, 16) ) / 255.0,
            green: CGFloat( strtoul( String(Array(hexaString.characters)[2...3]), nil, 16) ) / 255.0,
            blue:  CGFloat( strtoul( String(Array(hexaString.characters)[4...5]), nil, 16) ) / 255.0, alpha: 1 )
    }
}
```

Now `messageview.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexaString: "31D433")` should work.

**Update**

Note you used wrong ranges (I corrected them), and you probably need to write failable initializer for case when input string have wrong format.

Comment: Where do i need to place this extension shall i create new swift file for it.It should work in same class where i need to call

Comment: @bal-iphone you need to place this extension in global scope, which means you may create empty .swift file in your project with only this code, or you can use any other existed .swift files and put this code just outside of any class of this file